# How to select a proper analogue model in Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

Veins supports several analogue models for the wireless channel to address the large-scale, medium-scale and short-scale fading.

If I would like to try different models to compare them, which models should I set in the config.xml?
For example, can I try SimplePathLossModel+SimpleObstacleShadowing+NakagamiFading or BreakpointPathLossModel + LogNormalShadowing+JakesFading? What are the sensible combinations here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and thanks for using StackOverflow! Would you mind splitting this into two questions? This would make answers easier to find.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking what is possible from a technical standpoint or what is sensible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only use 2 analogue models at the same time and also the sensitivity would depend on what you want to emphasize in your output signal.

Comment: I disagree. Up to and including the current version, Veins 5.0, an arbitrary number of `AnalogueModel` instances can be used. They are simply [stored in a container](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.0/src/veins/base/phyLayer/BasePhyLayer.h#L135) that is iterated over at runtime. A full list of available `AnalogueModel` classes can be found [in the source code](https://github.com/sommer/veins/tree/veins-5.0/src/veins/modules/analogueModel). They key question to ask oneself is which combinations are *sensible*